# Converting polygons to contours based on value in polygon table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geometry, contour

I have the following data and have been asked to create a map that shows the same data set but displayed as contours.

Each polygon has a value in it's table called "count". The "count" field is used to show the graduated colors.

How would I go about converting the polygon data set into "contour" lines.  I understand that these are not true contours and I'm not sure why "they" want to see it displayed this way, but I need to do it if I can.

[image]

Comment: You might want to look at a heatmap as a way to visualize this information.  If you don't have a Spatial Analyst license it's going to be very difficult to generate contours.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I think I might try to use QGIS, though I don't have much experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the polygon to a raster using the count field, then using the contour tool to create contours. 
You will need either 3d or spatial for that though.

I believe there's a couple of free add-on's that can create contours if you don't have either license. 
GME is my favorite and I use that a lot.  (http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/contour.htm)